# Config error after updating from SVF2 beta servers to SVF2 production servers

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I have updated options.env and options.api from MD20xxx and D3S to be the following (based on [this blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/model-derivative-svf2-enhancements-part-1-viewer) and [this documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/basics/preperation/)):

```
        options.env = "AutodeskProduction2";
        options.api = "streamingV2";
```

This change resulted in the following [root config error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdWZc.png)

Is there anything else that may need to be updated to use the production servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new options are available starting from Forge Viewer `v7.48`. If you're referring to `v7.47` and older versions, then you need to use the beta options instead.

Kindly type `LMV_VIEWER_VERSION` in your web browser console to check the viewer version you're using.